# Is Clang lli API available?

Tags: clang, llvm

Is there any API for clang's [lli](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/lli.html) tool available? I'd like to use it but i can't invoke executable in my environment.

Comment: Isnt it for llvm ir rather than clang? Check the src in llvm/tools dir

Comment: you're right. it's more correct to write "llvm lli"